# How to skip or modify an index in pgloader?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, pgloader

I have a MySQL database with a FULLTEXT index that I wish to port to Postgres. When I create a Postgres database using [pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader), the index in Postgres becomes this:

```
"idx_33441_ibtsearchidx" gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, keywords))
```

Now, the `simple` configuration is not what I want; I, for this application, need `english`. I can manually enter an `ALTER INDEX` statement in psql after the migration, but I would like to fully automate the pgloader process (which worked beautifully in every other case!)

But how do I configure pgloader to do this? I seems like there are three possibilities:

1. Just put an `ALTER INDEX` statement into the pgloader script's `AFTER LOAD` section. But the problem is, I won't know the index name. Also I think this approach would be inefficient since an index was made and then a new one would be made after that.
2. Tell pgloader NOT to automatically make the fulltext index in Postgres. I don't know how to do this. Can it be done? I know how to exclude tables but not indexes. Here I can do the `ALTER INDEX` in the `AFTER LOAD` section no problem, because I can choose my own index name.
3. Specify exactly the full text index configuration I want in the pgloader script. I was unable to find an option for doing this in the pgloader reference. Is it possible?